# Code works without functions, doesn't work with functions?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to learn PyGame for my A-Level final project, and i've started with Atari Breakout. I have it at a stage where the ball bounces around and off the paddle. However the code is very untidy so I wanted to put it into functions.

The code works without functions:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))
pygame.display.set_caption('Breakout')
padX = 310
padY = 680
dotX = 150
dotY = 150
dotMX = -1
dotMY = -1
loss = False

while loss != True:
    DISPLAYSURF.fill(pygame.Color(0,0,0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            padX = event.pos[0]-75

        if padX < 3:
                padX = 3

        elif padX > 1127:
                padX = 1127

    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, pygame.Color(0, 0, 255),(padX, padY, 150, 30))

    dotX += dotMX
    dotY += dotMY

    if dotY >= 720 - 30:
        loss = True

    #hor colis
    if dotX <= 0 + 20:
        if dotMX == 1:
            dotMX = -1
        else:
            dotMX = 1
    elif dotX >= 1280 - 20:
        if dotMX == 1:
            dotMX = -1
        else:
            dotMX = 1
    #vert colis
    if dotY <= 0 - 20:
        if dotMY == 1:
            dotMY = -1
        else:
            dotMY = 1
    elif dotY >= 720 - 20:
        if dotMY == 1:
            dotMY = -1
        else:
            dotMY = 1
    #pad colis 
    if dotX >= padX and dotX <= padX + 150 and dotY == 665:
        if dotMY == 1:
            dotMY = -1
        else:
            dotMY = 1

    pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAYSURF, pygame.Color(255,0,0), (dotX, dotY), 20)

    pygame.display.update()
```

But here's it but sectioned into functions:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))


padX = 310
padY = 680
dotX = 150
dotY = 150
dotMX = -1
dotMY = -1
lives = 5


def main(padX, padY, dotX, dotY, dotMX, dotMY, lives):

    pygame.init()

    pygame.display.set_caption('Breakout')
    while lives != 0:
        DISPLAYSURF.fill(pygame.Color(0,0,0))
        for event in pygame.event.get():           
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                padX = event.pos[0]-75

            if padX < 3:
                    padX = 3

            elif padX > 1127:
                    padX = 1127

        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, pygame.Color(0, 0, 255),(padX, padY, 150, 30))

        dotX += dotMX
        dotY += dotMY

        colis(dotX, dotY, dotMX, dotMY, padX, padY, lives) 


        pygame.display.update() 

def colis(dotX, dotY, dotMX, dotMY, padX, padY, lives):


    if dotY >= 720 - 30:
        lives -= 1

    #hor colis
    if dotX <= 0 + 20:
        if dotMX == 1:
            dotMX = -1
        else:
            dotMX = 1
    elif dotX >= 1280 - 20:
        if dotMX == 1:
            dotMX = -1
        else:
            dotMX = 1
    #vert colis
    if dotY <= 0 - 20:
        if dotMY == 1:
            dotMY = -1
        else:
            dotMY = 1
    elif dotY >= 720 - 20:
        if dotMY == 1:
            dotMY = -1
        else:
            dotMY = 1
    #pad colis 
    if dotX >= padX and dotX <= padX + 150 and dotY == 665:
        if dotMY == 1:
            dotMY = -1
        else:
            dotMY = 1
    pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAYSURF, pygame.Color(255,0,0), (dotX, dotY), 20)


main(padX, padY, dotX, dotY, dotMX, dotMY, lives)
```

Can anyone see why it isn't working when separated into functions? Excuse me if its a stupidly simple thing to fix, i'm still quite inexperience with python. 
Thanks!

To clarify, with functions the ball just flies off to the top left and disappears!

Comment: are you getting any error? or its just not working?

Comment: Sorry I should've clarified. Without functions the ball bounces around and bounces off the paddle. In functions, the ball just flies off to the top left.

Comment: you are using global variables to call `main(padX, padY, dotX, dotY, dotMX, dotMY, lives) `, but these variables are never updated inside `main`.

Answer (score 0):

I can see couple of problems with the second block of cede. First one is related to formatting. You have line, like

```
if dotY >= 720 - 30
lives -= 1
```

This will not allow you to compile the code, as it's affected by incorrect indentation. 
Second problem is the fact, that you are passing some variables to functions, modify them inside of functions, but you are not returning them.

Function parameters are names. When you call a function Python binds these parameters to whatever objects you pass (via names in a caller scope).
Objects can be mutable (like lists) or immutable (like integers, strings in Python).

As dotX, dotY, dotMX, todMY, padX, padY, lives are integers, you cannot modify them with a side effect, they would need to be returned from a function. 
I'd suggest to create a class or use some data structure to pass and return all necessary parameters.

For a quick check, you can modify the `colis` function by adding a return statemet at the end of it, like

```
return (dotX, dotY, dotMX, dotMY, padX, padY, lives)
```

and changing the call to the function in `main` function like this

```
dotX, dotY, dotMX, dotMY, padX, padY, lives = colis(dotX, dotY, dotMX, dotMY, padX, padY, lives)
```

After you will get the point, you can start further refactoring as my updates are not really elegant and clean as they should be.

Comment: Oh wow, that fixed it. The incorrect indentation is just my inexperience with Stackoverflow. We haven't done classes yet, I will be implementing them whenever I learn how.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing things to a function (`colis`) redefining them inside the function, but those changes aren't reflected outside of the function (that's just how Python works).

The *simplest* change is to simply return the three variables that are changed in `colis` and propogate those changes into `main`:

```
def colis(dotX, dotY, dotMX, dotMY, padX, padY, lives):
    ...
    pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAYSURF, pygame.Color(255,0,0), (dotX, dotY), 20)

    return dotMX, dotMY, lives # This line
```

and

```
def main(padX, padY, dotX, dotY, dotMX, dotMY, lives):
    ...
        dotX += dotMX
        dotY += dotMY

        dotMX, dotMY, lives = colis(dotX, dotY, dotMX, dotMY, padX, padY, lives)  # This line

        pygame.display.update()
```

A "better" approach (down the road, maybe) might be to define and instantiate class objects for those parameters (e.g. `Dot`, `Pad`) that you could pass to the `colis` function.

(Full Code)

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))


padX = 310
padY = 680
dotX = 150
dotY = 150
dotMX = -1
dotMY = -1
lives = 5


def main(padX, padY, dotX, dotY, dotMX, dotMY, lives):
    pygame.init()

    pygame.display.set_caption('Breakout')
    while lives != 0:
        DISPLAYSURF.fill(pygame.Color(0,0,0))
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                padX = event.pos[0]-75

            if padX < 3:
                    padX = 3

            elif padX > 1127:
                    padX = 1127

        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, pygame.Color(0, 0, 255),(padX, padY, 150, 30))

        dotX += dotMX
        dotY += dotMY

        dotMX, dotMY, lives = colis(dotX, dotY, dotMX, dotMY, padX, padY, lives)  # This line

        pygame.display.update()

def colis(dotX, dotY, dotMX, dotMY, padX, padY, lives):
    if dotY >= 720 - 30:
        lives -= 1

    #hor colis
    if dotX <= 0 + 20:
        if dotMX == 1:
            dotMX = -1
        else:
            dotMX = 1
    elif dotX >= 1280 - 20:
        if dotMX == 1:
            dotMX = -1
        else:
            dotMX = 1
    #vert colis
    if dotY <= 0 - 20:
        if dotMY == 1:
            dotMY = -1
        else:
            dotMY = 1
    elif dotY >= 720 - 20:
        if dotMY == 1:
            dotMY = -1
        else:
            dotMY = 1
    #pad colis
    if dotX >= padX and dotX <= padX + 150 and dotY == 665:
        if dotMY == 1:
            dotMY = -1
        else:
            dotMY = 1
    pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAYSURF, pygame.Color(255,0,0), (dotX, dotY), 20)

    return dotMX, dotMY, lives # This line


main(padX, padY, dotX, dotY, dotMX, dotMY, lives)
```

Comment: These edits still give the same output. Should I maybe change the variables to local variables?

Comment: It worked for me, I'll edit the post with the full code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's a simple fix for your code, where you're not using the global variables properly:

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *

DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))


padX = 310
padY = 680
dotX = 150
dotY = 150
dotMX = -1
dotMY = -1
lives = 5


def main():
    global padX, padY, dotX, dotY, dotMX, dotMY, lives

    pygame.init()

    pygame.display.set_caption('Breakout')
    while lives != 0:
        DISPLAYSURF.fill(pygame.Color(0, 0, 0))
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                padX = event.pos[0] - 75

            if padX < 3:
                padX = 3

            elif padX > 1127:
                padX = 1127

        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, pygame.Color(
            0, 0, 255), (padX, padY, 150, 30))

        dotX += dotMX
        dotY += dotMY

        colis()

        pygame.display.update()


def colis():
    global padX, padY, dotX, dotY, dotMX, dotMY, lives

    if dotY >= 720 - 30:
        lives -= 1

    # hor colis
    if dotX <= 0 + 20:
        if dotMX == 1:
            dotMX = -1
        else:
            dotMX = 1
    elif dotX >= 1280 - 20:
        if dotMX == 1:
            dotMX = -1
        else:
            dotMX = 1
    # vert colis
    if dotY <= 0 - 20:
        if dotMY == 1:
            dotMY = -1
        else:
            dotMY = 1
    elif dotY >= 720 - 20:
        if dotMY == 1:
            dotMY = -1
        else:
            dotMY = 1
    # pad colis
    if dotX >= padX and dotX <= padX + 150 and dotY == 665:
        if dotMY == 1:
            dotMY = -1
        else:
            dotMY = 1
    pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAYSURF, pygame.Color(255, 0, 0), (dotX, dotY), 20)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And here's your code a little bit refactored, using [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and a more OOP approach (sort of):

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *


class Game():

    def __init__(self):
        self.pad_x = 310
        self.pad_y = 680
        self.dot_x = 150
        self.dot_y = 150
        self.dot_mx = -1
        self.dot_my = -1
        self.lives = 5

    def run(self):
        self.display = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))
        pygame.init()
        pygame.display.set_caption('Breakout')

        while self.lives != 0:
            self.display.fill(pygame.Color(0, 0, 0))

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                    self.pad_x = event.pos[0] - 75

                if self.pad_x < 3:
                    self.pad_x = 3

                elif self.pad_x > 1127:
                    self.pad_x = 1127

            pygame.draw.rect(self.display, pygame.Color(
                0, 0, 255), (self.pad_x, self.pad_y, 150, 30))

            self.dot_x += self.dot_mx
            self.dot_y += self.dot_my

            self.colis()

            pygame.display.update()

    def colis(self):
        if self.dot_y >= 720 - 30:
            self.lives -= 1

        # hor colis
        if self.dot_x <= 0 + 20:
            if self.dot_mx == 1:
                self.dot_mx = -1
            else:
                self.dot_mx = 1
        elif self.dot_x >= 1280 - 20:
            if self.dot_mx == 1:
                self.dot_mx = -1
            else:
                self.dot_mx = 1

        # vert colis
        if self.dot_y <= 0 - 20:
            if self.dot_my == 1:
                self.dot_my = -1
            else:
                self.dot_my = 1
        elif self.dot_y >= 720 - 20:
            if self.dot_my == 1:
                self.dot_my = -1
            else:
                self.dot_my = 1

        # pad colis
        if self.dot_x >= self.pad_x and self.dot_x <= self.pad_x + 150 and self.dot_y == 665:
            if self.dot_my == 1:
                self.dot_my = -1
            else:
                self.dot_my = 1

        pygame.draw.circle(self.display, pygame.Color(
            255, 0, 0), (self.dot_x, self.dot_y), 20)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Game().run()
```